# Can the macbook air trackpad play nice with the iOS simulator?

Tags: macos, ios, macbook-pro, trackpad, xcode

Does anyone knows if (and how) I can get my MacBook Air trackpad to feel more natural when used with the iOS simulator ?

It should be easier to use the iOS simulator with the trackpad - but it's not, it's way more difficult to scroll :-( It feels weird but it's the only time I wish I had a *mouse* on my mac book air - to emulate a touch screen :-|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunatly the simulator was not built to understand multi-touch gestures which is strange considering the rest of the OS has. I think you will just need to wait until Apple updates the simulator.

Answer (score 4):

This might help, I posted this elsewhere:

**Enable 3 finger drag**:

1. From the Apple menu, choose System Preferences.
2. Click the Accessibility icon
3. Choose Mouse & Trackpad from the options on the left
4. Click Trackpad Options
5. Place a checkmark next to "Enable dragging"
6. From the related pop-up menu, choose “three finger drag” so there's a checkmark next to it
7. Click OK

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204609

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [iOS Simulator Plus](https://github.com/n3rd4n1/iOS-Simulator-Plus) utility I wrote. It's not really a 100% solution but I think it is one step more convenient.